# Are there any database administration tools that runs in AWS Lambda?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Are there any tools for database administration that can be deployed in AWS Lambda? My usecase is i've aurora serverless running inside a vpc and I want an AWS Lambda function to be able to visualize, clear and delete datas so developers do not need to get inside bastion hosts everytime they need to clear a row.

Comment: When an AWS Lambda function is invoked, it runs some code and then returns a response. It is not suitable for "visualizing" data, but it can certainly connect to a database and run some SQL commands. Your main concern would be how to trigger the Lambda function and how to ensure that only authorized people activate it.

Comment: hey, i managed to write a simple tool that runs on lambda and lets the user to perform queries in a postgres database and get output back in a table. @Marcin

Comment: Repo: https://github.com/regmicmahesh/serverless-query-runner

Answer (score 0):

There is [Data API for Aurora Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html) which allows you to use regular AWS SDK (e.g. boto3) to query your databases in Aurora Serverless.

Comment: I was actually looking for a tool as a developer/devops would use to run queries using a web UI or something. Sorry, if my question was not clear.

Comment: @MaheshC.Regmi You can use DATA API from AWS Console.